# Button's Text Cycle Through String-Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a button that when clicked, the text inside changes. I'm trying to accomplish this with an array in my strings.xml, thinking that the onClick will do a for loop through the string-array

```
<string-array name="RG_answers">
     <item>text 1</item><!--Of course this is example text-->
     <item>text 2</item>
     <item>text 3</item>
</string-array>
```

I don't know if I'm just not Googling correctly, or what. Inside my `onCreate()` my button is basic

```
 mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

So basic that it's only helpful (if that) by providing the names I called it. Is it possible/feasible? From what I've found I haven't seen anyone ask a question like this.

Comment: I feel like this is sarcastic. What can I do to provide more clarity for you? I will edit the OP accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cycle the text on each button click and go back to the start of the array when it reaches the end?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So when it first launches the text in the button would say "text 1", when clicked would change to "text 2" etc etc, than when it hits the end of the array, loops back to "text 1".

Comment: you need to set all the text one by one to the button when you click it just one time?

Comment: That was the plan. The thing is, I'm not entirely sure this is the right/best way to do this. I hardly doubt it is, I'm still very new to java/android development.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to loop through the string-array?

Yes, change the button text using `button.setText(text);` Keep a counter as global variable so that you can cycle through the list of 'button text' you have mentioned.

eg: `button.setText(array[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

You need three steps:

```
//1 Declare an index outside onClick:
int currentIndex=0;

//2- Read the answers:
Resources res = getResources();
myStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.RG_answers);

//3- iterate thru them inside onClick:
mTrueButton.setText(myStrings[(currentIndex++)%(myStrings.length)]);
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something because declaring `myStrings` is throwing at my "cannot resolve symbol" when I declare it inside the onCreate(). I declared `String[] myStrings;` outside of the onCreate() and it doesn't display any syntax errors. However, this causes the app to instantly crash when the instance is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
private int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String[] btnText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RG_answers);
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTrueButton.setText(btnText[count]);
            if (count < btnText.length - 1) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Went off and a friend of mine ended up helping me with getting the solution. Your answer is very similar to what I got working, as he and I ended up going the route of `mTrueButton.setText(RG_arr[i].toString());` inside the onClick(). I'm not certain whether to mark yours as the answer, or post my own, as I can see yours working just as well as our solution.